# Return data from database as selected value in dropdown

Tags: php

I am trying to return data from my database into a dropdown.

Here is my dropdown without the return:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
  <select class="form-control select2" id="status" name="status" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="1">Active</option>
    <option value="0">Inactive</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The following statement returns an 1 or 0:

```
SELECT status FROM users WHERE id=1
```

In this case value `1` means `Active` and `0` means `Inactive`.

Does someone know how I can present the returned value as the selected value?

For textboxes I am using the following script:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required="required" value="<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "db";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id='". $_GET['id'] ."';
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row["name"]));
    }
  } else {
  echo "";
  }
  $conn->close();
?>">
```

**Edit 1:**

I get an Error when I try this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Status</label>';
    echo '<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">';
    echo '<select class="form-control select2" id="geactiveerd" name="geactiveerd" style="width: 100%;">';
    echo '<option ($row["status"] == "1") ? "selected="selected"' : '"value="1">Active</option>';
    echo '<option ($row["status"] == "0") ? "selected="selected"' : '"value="0">Inactive</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
} else {
```

Comment: simply use `<option echo ($row["status"] == '1') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''value="1">Active</option>`

Comment: And how do I need to add the value for `value='0'`? Will the script show the value that is not selected?

Comment: Same for the `value 0` as well.
`<option echo ($row["status"] == '0') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''value="0">Inactive</option>`

Comment: Here is a question? If you mean 1 = Active and 2 = Inactive the you need to use 2 instead of 0 for inactive as you describe in the question. 
*The following statement returns an 1 or 2:*

Comment: It should be 1 or 0. I changed it in my question.

Comment: Then just use my first and second comment

Comment: I get an error for the `echo '<option` lines. See edit 1 in my first post

Comment: So wait for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the while loop shows for the answer-

Avoide the HTML and PHP tag combination.

```
<?php 
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Status</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <select class="form-control select2" id="geactiveerd" name="geactiveerd" style="width: 100%;">
    <option <?php echo ($row["status"] == "1") ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> value="1">Active</option>
    <option <?php echo ($row["status"] == "0") ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> value="0">Inactive</option>
    </select>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I think something is missing or `?>` in the option is not on the right place.

Comment: I still get an error. And the color in my editor for the second option doenst look right.